# Android: Error recording video using camera2

Tags: android, audio, video, android-camera2

I'm quite new with Android and, for my thesis, I need to use an app that needs to record video with audio for a pre-defined period of time. The code is based on [Google's example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video). However, the camera fails to record and the app crashes.

So far, I've been trying out many suggestions from people more knowledgeable than me in this (checking libraries, re-checking the process of opening and closing the camera, among others), until I eventually ended up adapting my code with Google's example and it resulted in the code below. However, the same kind of errors keep happening and I can't figure out why or how to overcome them.

```
package com.example.filipa.eyetracker;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Calibration extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Camera2Video";
    private static final SparseIntArray DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final SparseIntArray INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    static {
        INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 270);
        INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 180);
        INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 90);
        INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 0);
    }

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;

    private TextureView  mTextureView; //A {@link TextureView} for camera preview.
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice; //A reference to the opened {@link android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice}

    // Handles several lifecycle events on a {@link TextureView}
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
            = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
            openCamera(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
            configureTransform(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };

    private Size mPreviewSize; //The {@link android.util.Size} of camera preview.
    private Size mVideoSize; //The {@link android.util.Size} of video recording.
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder; //MediaRecorder
    private boolean mIsRecordingVideo; //Whether the app is recording video now
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread; //An additional thread for running tasks that shouldn't block the UI.
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler; //A {@link Handler} for running tasks in the background.
    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock
            = new Semaphore(1); //A {@link Semaphore} to prevent the app from exiting before closing the camera.

    private int milliseconds;

    //{@link CameraDevice.StateCallback} is called when {@link CameraDevice} changes its status.
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            startPreview();
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            if (null != mTextureView) {
                configureTransform(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    private String mCameraId;
    private CameraCharacteristics characteristics;

    private File mVideoFolder;
    private String mNextVideoAbsolutePath;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession; //A reference to the current {@link android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession} for preview.

    private int cdotnumber;
    int[] cdots = {R.drawable.calgelo, R.drawable.calgelo, R.drawable.calgelo};

    /*
     * In this sample, we choose a video size with 3x4 aspect ratio. Also, we don't use sizes
     * larger than 1080p, since MediaRecorder cannot handle such a high-resolution video.
     *
     * @param choices The list of available sizes
     * @return The video size
     */
    private static Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
        for (Size size : choices) {
            if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 4 / 3 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
                return size;
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable video size");
        return choices[choices.length - 1];
    }

    /*
     * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, chooses the smallest one whose
     * width and height are at least as large as the respective requested values, and whose aspect
     * ratio matches with the specified value.
     *
     * @param choices     The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output class
     * @param width       The minimum desired width
     * @param height      The minimum desired height
     * @param aspectRatio The aspect ratio
     * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
     */
    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
        // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
        int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w &&
                    option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }

        // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        /* Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
         SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
         a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
         hide the navigation bar.*/
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calibration);

        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        if (mVideoFolder == null){createVideoFolder();}
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        new CountDownTimer(15000, 3000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                delay(1);

                openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                startRecordingVideo();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                stopRecordingVideo();
                closeCamera();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void delay(int seconds){
        milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        nextDot();           //add your code here
                    }
                }, milliseconds);
            }
        });
    }

    public void nextDot() {
        if (cdotnumber < (cdots.length)) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageDrawable(getDrawable(cdots[cdotnumber]));
        } else {
            stopRecordingVideo();
            closeCamera();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PostCalibration.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        cdotnumber++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    /*
     * Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    /*
     * Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Application will not run without camera services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Application will not run without audio permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Permission successfully granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Application will not run with storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                mCameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[1];

                // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
                characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

                if (map == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get available preview/video sizes");
                }

            /* TODO: Increase camera exposure
            Range<Integer> range1 = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE);
            minExposure = range1.getLower();
            maxExposure = range1.getUpper();
            */

                mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        width, height, mVideoSize);

                configureTransform(width, height);
                mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Calibration.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
                    }
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, null);
                } else {
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, null);
                }

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
                // device this code runs.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "NullPointerException has occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        try {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
            closePreviewSession();
            if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (null != mMediaRecorder) {
                mMediaRecorder.release();
                mMediaRecorder = null;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.");
        } finally {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Start the camera preview
     */
    private void startPreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            closePreviewSession();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(previewSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            mPreviewSession = session;
                            updatePreview();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Unable to setup camera preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, mBackgroundHandler);

        }catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Update the camera preview. {@link #startPreview()} needs to be called in advance.
     */
    private void updatePreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice){
            return;
        }
        try{
            setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewBuilder);
            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            thread.start();
            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){

        }
    }

    private void closePreviewSession() {
        if (mPreviewSession != null){
            mPreviewSession.close();
            mPreviewSession = null;
        }
    }

    private void setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    }

    /*
     * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
     * This method should not to be called until the camera preview size is determined in
     * openCamera, or until the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
     *
     * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
     * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
     */
    //TODO: Code for configureTransform - don't know if needed
    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        if(null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize){
            return;
        }
    }

    private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException{
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()){
            createVideoFileName();
        }
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private void startRecordingVideo(){
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize){
            return;
        }
        try{

            closePreviewSession();
            setUpMediaRecorder();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;

            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();

            //Set up Surface for the camera preview
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            //Set up Surface for the MediaRecorder
            Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

            /* TODO: Increase the camera exposure
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            exp = (int)(maxExposure * 0.35);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, exp);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);*/

            //Start a capture session
            //Once the session starts, we can update the UI and start recording
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mIsRecordingVideo = true;
                            mMediaRecorder.start();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecordingVideo(){
        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        //Stop recording
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = null;
        startPreview();
    }

    private void createVideoFolder() {
        File movieFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        mVideoFolder = new File(movieFile, "camera2VideoImage");
        if(!mVideoFolder.exists()) {
            mVideoFolder.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private void createVideoFileName() throws IOException{
        if (mVideoFolder == null){
            createVideoFolder();
        }

        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String prepend = "VIDEO_" +"CAL_"+ timestamp + "_";
        File videoFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".mp4", mVideoFolder);
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }


    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

To give you some context, before running the code that throws error, the app runs some activities that allow the user to set some parameters that are used later on. When you reach this specific activity, it starts running as is supposed to, but after a few seconds, it crashes and on debug it enters a loop of trying to record and failing.

The intented behaviour is for the screen to show an image of a white plus sign for someone to look at, while it records using the frontal camera.

Some errors that are stated while debugging and that I couldn't figure out. Here's the [full stack trace](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/K4gevACe). I'd appreciate a lot any help/suggestions that you may provide me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Errors tagged with `E/libc:` in this case seems to be harmful and not related to your problem. According to docs `MediaRecorder` throws `IllegalStateException` in `stop` method only if it called before `start`. Try to check `mIsRecordingVideo` at your `stopRecordingVideo` method. Seems it called more than once. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#stop()

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems that is probably where errors start occurring  (in `stopRecordingVideo`) since I just got 
`E/CameraDevice-1-LE: submitRequestList - cannot use a surface that wasn't configured
E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 8`

It doesn't look like it's stop being called before start however but from the configuration of the surface and I'm not exactly sure what that means in my code. Do you have any clues about this? Thank you once again

Comment: Error comes from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libmedia/mediarecorder.cpp#558), constants come from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2/include/media/mediarecorder.h#96). 8 corresponds to `MEDIA_RECORDER_PREPARED`.

Comment: `state: 8` means that `MediaRecorder#prepare` was called, but `MediaRecorder#start` wasn't. It would be very helpful if you update your question with complete stack traces. It is also unclear how many times `startRecordingVideo` called before crash.

Comment: I see... In the meantime, I updated the question with the full thing. Hope it helps clearing out what's going wrong with it.

Comment: Ana, have you solved this problem?